# Mix CATextLayer and CAScrollLayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, catextlayer, quartz-core

I need a scrollable CATextLayer to display a NSAttributedString.
Is there any way to mix both layers, or to add a scroll to CATextLayer or to display text in a CAScrollLayer?

Sorry if the question isn't very exact.
Thanks!

EDIT: I haven't seen that the CALayer is scrollable.
Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CALayer (and CATextLayer) can be scrolled

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your example to scroll the layer programmatically:

```
- (void)scroll {
    [scrollLayer scrollToPoint:scrollPoint];
    scrollPoint.x += 10;
    [self performSelector:_cmd withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

and add this at the end of the initialize method:

```
scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[self scroll];
```